# Question about ifstream on own executable

Tags: c++, memory, ifstream

Can a program read itself using ifstream, without some sort of corruption or failures ???

Answer (score 2):

Read? Yes. you get the file name as the first member of the `argv` array in the `main` parameters. Make sure to open for read only (ios_base::in).

Comment: How does it work? How can it read itself and execute itself at the same time? (I am new to programming by the way)

Comment: The program is not executed straight out of the hard drive. In simple terms, it is loaded from disk into memory by the operating system and then it is executed from memory.

Comment: Then why is it impossible to delete an executable while it is running?

Comment: @jack -- It's not impossible, on any reasonable operating system.

Comment: Can you please me give me some more information? This is interesting, I would like to know more

Comment: @Nemo, @Jack - It is impossible on some "unreasonable" operating systems because they memory map the file during execution to be able to swap it in by segments.  :-)

Comment: @jack although inquisitiveness can be a good thing, this isn't going to teach you anything much about programming, if that is your goal.

Comment: @Bo:  You can certainly "unlink" a running executable (as in "rm").  What you cannot do is overwrite it.

Comment: @Nemo Unlink of a running exe on *nix deletes nothing. The OS has a link to the file.

Comment: @Nemo - I thought the "unreasonable" one was W*****s. :-)

Comment: Yes @Neil, I know.  And if you are going to be pedantic about "unlink" vs. "delete", then you are wrong; what the OS maintains is not called a "link".

Comment: So on Windows it is impossible??

Comment: @Jack - what's impossible? Read the executable that executes - yes, it's possible. Delete it? You might get sharing violations or get deadlocked (I don't think Windows does that deferred unlinking @Nemo mentioned).

Comment: @littleadv: depends on the compiler settings/exe header actually. You can flag an executable as "running from CD or network", in which case Windows will page to swap instead of keeping a handle open.